# ArrayList to Array in java 1.4.2

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Stuck using an old java version, so I am not able to cast my array list to a string, and was wondering how I can successfully convert my arrayList to an array.  here is my code:

```
    String racesArray[] = request.getParameterValues("races");
    ArrayList races = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < racesArray.length; ++i) {
        String s = racesArray[i];
        if (s != null && s.length() > 0) {
            races.add(s);
        }
    }
    final String[] racesArray1 = (String[])races.toArray(new Object[races.size()]);
```

The above codes gives me a classCastException

EDIT:  Changed to avoid confusion on variables

Comment: You start with an array. Why do you have the middle step? But what's wrong with your solution?

Comment: @sotiriosDelimanolis I have to remove nulls and empty strings, but I need it in an array to send to the database.  The variables in the original array are from a form

Comment: Check out the Strings in the String array. They are not "Strings".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] racesArray = { "raceWhite", "raceBlack", "raceInd", "raceAsian", "raceHaw", "raceInter", "raceUnknown" };
List races = Arrays.asList(racesArray);
String[] racesArray1 = (String[]) races.toArray(new String[races.size()]);
```

Take attention on the last line: **new String** not **new Object** -- this was the main reason of your problem.

Good luck with Java 1.4.2 :) and I recommend the book of Joshua Bloch "Effective Java" 1st edition. It is for Java 1.4 and touches the most important aspects of everyday programming.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem** is in the **first line**.

Your `String array` does not contain `Strings`.

```
String[] racesArray = {raceWhite, raceBlack, raceInd, raceAsian, raceHaw, raceInter, raceUnknown}
```

Declare it as "Strings"

```
String[] racesArray = {"raceWhite", "raceBlack", "raceInd", "raceAsian", "raceHaw"};
```

---

**Problem 2:**

You need to create a `new String[]` and not `new Object[]`

```
final String[] racesArray1 = (String[])races.toArray(new String[races.size()]);
```

Remember, **String is an Object**. **Object doss not extend from String**.

---

Comment: They are string variables from a form, I was hoping it would be easier to understand then going through all the "getParameterValues" mumbo jumbo

Comment: Pretty sure those are variables, as none of those items as strings makes sense as a "race". So somewhere we can't see: `String raceWhite = "White";` etc.

Comment: since he is using java 1.4 i dont think he can use ArrayList<String>. generics came into play only after 1.5 :)

Comment: @BlackPanther Thanks missed 1.4. from the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can to it this way:

```
int countNull = 0;
for(String s : racesArray)
    if(s == null)
        countNull++;

int i = 0;
String arr = new String[racesArray.length-countNull];
for(String s : racesArray) {
    if(s != null) {
        arr[i++] = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: this won't work, as the code in the question is to eliminate null values from the string[]. your code just does a copy of the array.